# Failed to compile "134_flatten.sol": solc: exit status 1Error: expected identifier but got 'Number'

Tags: ethereum, polygon, solidity, contract

I get a compiler error when trying to compile a contract.  I get the following error when the app tries to compile the sol file. The error is: Failed to compile "134_flatten.sol":solc:exit status 1Error:
Expected identifier but got'Number'->:1733:10|1733
|contract 134 is ERC71`PresetMinterPauserAutoId  {|^^^
Help would be greatly appreciated. The contract is below.
Thanks in advance.

```
    constructor() public
    ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId("134", "134", "https://protomock.com:5000/item/view/134/")
    {}

}
```

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting of code when adding here, it is my first time to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Someone already created an nft token or collection with that title and once changing the name of the collection everything was fine.